How to determine if path is file or folder using Dart
I need to determine if a path is folder or a file using Dart.
The FileSystem class has methods: isDirectory and isFile.
I don't understand how to access FileSystem class and these class methods.
Could you please provide your suggestions.
Thank You

If you're using package:file, then LocalFileSystem().isDirectory(path) or LocalFileSystem().isFile(path).  Or you can directly call FileSystemEntity.isDirectory(path) or FileSystemEntity.isFile(path) from dart:io.

You can try something like that:
import 'dart:io';

Future<String> isFileOrDirectory(String path) async {
  try {
    final isDirectory = await Directory(path).exists();
    final isFile = await File(path).exists();

    if (isDirectory) {
      return 'directory';
    } else if (isFile) {
      return 'file';
    } else {
      return 'error';
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return 'error';
  }
}

void main() async {
  String result = await isFileOrDirectory('./mydirectory');
  print(result);
}

Feel free to adapt this code to your needs
===EDIT===
According to @pskink, you can also use this:
Future<String> isFileOrDirectory(String path) async {
  FileSystemEntityType type = await FileSystemEntity.type(path);

  return type.toString();
}

void main() async {
  String result = await isFileOrDirectory('./mydirectory');
  print(result);
}


no need to reinvent the wheel: there is a static FileSystemEntity.type method that not only answers if a path is file or directory but also can return types like: link / notFound / pipe /
unixDomainSock - the official docs say: '''Finds the type of file system object that a path points to.'''
